# Selenium python cannot click on object when trying to find by class name

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

A relatively simple issue, I am trying to click on the "Car" button on this site, using Selenium to do this, I have the following code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import  ChromeDriverManager

def runScript():
    with open("plates.txt") as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser.get('https://www.myplates.com.au/#/')
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('col-3 col-md-3 rfh-item-box ng-star-inserted').click();


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runScript()
```

Now I wish to click on this button here

This is located on this site

[This is the button I wish to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAcIn.png)

https://www.myplates.com.au/#/

I also need to select the text drop box and write some input into it how would I also go about doing this.

Thank you any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.myplates.com.au/#/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row rfh-menu-list']//div[@class='row']//div[contains(@class, 'rfh-type-item') and contains(., 'Car')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```